# A blank screen after logging in from suspend on Debian

Tags: debian, login, suspend, screen-lock

I have installed Debian 8.7.1 on my Asus n552-vw laptop. The problem is that after going to suspend and trying to login again, my laptop works(fan and LEDs and caps lock work) but there is no screen! I tried gnome, Kde, Lxde, xfce desktop environments but no difference!

After that I must shutdown my laptop by keeping power button! and when I power on my pc again I see some failed frimware errors about `nouveau n117_fuc409c` and `nouveau fuc409fc`! but pc works fine(unless above problem in suspension)

How can I fix that?

This is the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:191b] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1d8d]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1903] (rev 07)
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:139b] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1d8d]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
```

Comment: Do you try run command prompt? Ctrl+Alt+F2/F3 etc?

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2` For firmware stuff if not on your system `apt install bumblebee prime` but I don't think, this solve your Problem.

Comment: @SanHolo: no they don't work on that situation(after going to suspend)

Comment: @Bahamaut: I did edit my question, also couldnt install bumblebee prime(Unable to locate package prime)

Comment: I don't know why, but in Debian 8.5 with similar behavior the workaround is to press `control-alt-F1` to go to tty1 and then back to tty7 with `control-alt-F7`.  As a permanent workaround i changed power setting to never sleep / never suspend but only turn off display after some idle time.

Comment: Yes, I had similar problem with Debian 8.5 too but I wish the problem will be solved by installing Debian 8.7.1, but unfortunately the problem persists.

I tried your suggestion but I get only a black screen with backlight by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 and a colored stripe screen! and I must hard shutdown my pc with keeping power button again!